# When does the $op parameter of hook_search() get defined as 'search'?

Tags: drupal, search, drupal-6

**Edit**

The basic question here is "when does the $op parameter get defined as 'search'"?

I am trying to create a custom search in an implementation of hook_search(). I have been looking through the Drupal documentation for the method here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_search/6

I know the method is running because I can slip a `die('killed inside of implementation of hook_search()')` into the top of the function and see the output.

In the following code, the script is never killed so that I can see the output `search caught inside of my_search()`. This leads me to believe that the 'search' case of the switch statement is never firing. Does anybody know where I might go from here?

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_search()
*/
function my_search($op = 'search', $keys = NULL) {
  switch($op)
  {
    case 'search':
        die('search caught inside of my_search()');
        break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first.

Assuming your module is called 'my', try to go to URL /search/my/whatever - probably you will see access forbidden page (assuming you do not have anything more in your code besides what you have pasted in your question).

That's because you do not return anything when search module calls your hook with $op = 'name' (see _search_menu() in search.module). You need to return "a translated name defining the type of items that are searched for with this module ('content', 'users', ...)" - see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_search/6 And access forbidden gone.

Once this is done, search will call your hook again (actually, there are quite a few calls, you can for example drupal_set_message($op) in your hook to see them all), and one of those calls will be with $op = "search" as well (coming from search_data() in search.module).

Comment: Thanks Maciej! I never put it together that 'name' and 'search' operations were connected :-)